# Handling print window in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There is a print button in my application. When I click on the button print windows open with cancel and print button.

I want to click on cancel button in the print window.

I know handling print window is not possible using selenium webdriver alone. I tried using Robot class. But it is not working.

```
WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.joecolantonio.com/SeleniumTestPage.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(2000);
//clicking on the print button      
driver.findElement(By.id("printButton")).click();
//print window opens 
//creating robot class object    
Robot r = new Robot();
r.delay(1000);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

The print window opens but nothing happens after that. I was expecting escape button will make the window exit but its does not happens. But manually when I press escape button print window disappears.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can handle print page window using javascript executor in selenium.
following codes are  c#.
If your program is stuck after opening `window.print();` which in my case it was happening, try to use the following javascript code instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 0);
```

this will release your application and you can work with the print page.
then you can switch to the print page simply by the following line:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

then you can get the JSPath of any element in print window and interact with it

```
(IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript($"return {JSPath}").Click();
```

A complete example of this, is as follows where print window will be opened then the cancel button will be clicked after 2 seconds.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 0);");
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
Thread.Sleep(2000);
string JSPath = "document.querySelector('body>print-preview-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('#sidebar').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-button-strip').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-button.cancel-button')";
IWebElement cancelBtn = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript($"return {JSPath}");
cancelBtn.Click();
```

Since the elements in print window exist in the shadow root you cannot select them by selenium web driver that's why I used Javascript Executor to get the cancel button.

Comment: This should be accepted answer . Worked nicely for me

Answer (score 1):

Use tab and then click escape.I think it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using Robot is not something I would recommend to handling the print preview page as it will bite you back when you will be running your tests in [Parallel mode](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+Execution).

You could click "Cancel" button as follows:

1. Switch to the Print Preview window using [driver.switchTo()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--) function:

   ```
   driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().stream().filter(handle -> !handle.equals(driver.getWindowHandle())).findAny().get());
   ```
2. Find `preview-app` [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) element using i.e. [XPath](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector) and convert it into a [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)

   ```
   WebElement printPreviewApp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//print-preview-app"));
   WebElement printPreviewAppContent = (WebElement) driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", printPreviewApp);
   ```
3. Find `preview-header` Shadow DOM element using i.e. [CSS](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-css-selector) and convert into a Selenium's Web Element

   ```
   WebElement printPreviewHeader = printPreviewAppContent.findElement(By.cssSelector("print-preview-header"));
   WebElement printPreviewHeaderContent = (WebElement) driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", printPreviewHeader);
   ```
4. Locate `Cancel` button and click it

   ```
   printPreviewHeaderContent.findElement(By.cssSelector("paper-button[class*=cancel]")).click();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for someone else who still looking solution
To download save as a pdf from the print pop-up window from any web

Add argument

```
options.addArguments("kiosk-printing");
```

This will prevent to open any popups from clicking on any print button.But a window dialog folder will open to download the file as a pdf.

Now you need to input the file name and press enter button. For this, we will use the robot class

```
StringSelection s=new StringSelection("remotePetrol_report.pdf"); // Set the File Name
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(s,null);
        //native keystrokes for CTRL, V, and ENTER keys
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```